# How to display large set of data in a data table

Tags: react-native

I want to show large set of data in a single screen in data table where I can sort data, search data, filter data and add a footer to the table that is always visible at the bottom

[data table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUEYM.png)

Comment: **Side note:** "data" never has a "plural" version "datas" in the English language - "data" itself is already what describes multiple pieces of information .....

Comment: Thanks for the information and sorry for my poor English  @marc_s,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table.html.
It provides pagination on the table.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DataTable>
        <DataTable.Header>
          <DataTable.Title>Dessert</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title right>Calories</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title right>Fat</DataTable.Title>
        </DataTable.Header>

        <DataTable.Row>
          <DataTable.Cell>Frozen yogurt</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell right>159</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell right>6.0</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>

        <DataTable.Row>
          <DataTable.Cell>Ice cream sandwich</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell right>237</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell right>8.0</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>

        <DataTable.Pagination
          page={1}
          numberOfPages={3}
          onPageChange={(page) => { console.log(page); }}
          label="1-2 of 6"
        />
      </DataTable>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ Burhan Yilmaz, I will try this and I will update to you,

Comment: I couldn't use react-native-paper. It gives me TypeError.  _undefined is not an object(evaluating '_reactNativePaper.DataTable.Header")_. I used the same code as above